# Ubuntu launcher bar resets automatically everytime I restart computer

Tags: 14.04, launcher

Hi I tried to delete/remove gstreamer from my Ubuntu. In process I think I deleted some gnome plugin or some other important plugin. Now everytime I restart my computer, the icon bar resets. (The vertical bar on the left hand side[image])

What package should I install to make this as before ? Or is there a reset settings or packages anywhere ?

Am new to linux so please forgive my wrong lingo. Am using ubuntu 14.04

As seen below I have pinned some icons I want i.e. eclipse and chrome to the launcher. 
Now when I restart the computer, all the default stuff comes back i.e. firefox, libre office etc .

Edit : 
I tried the command **setsid unity**

After trying this command I could a see a lot of error messages on the command line and it continued to do something i.e. it did not quit the command execution. Following file contains the error and the output.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bp4mmntgz5gi8s3/keep.txt?dl=0

Comment: I'm confused. Can you [edit] your question to provide some clarity for us? I'm not sure if you mean the launcher (defaults to the left side) or the menu bar (defaults to the top). Perhaps you could give us a screenshot (upload to imgur.com and provide a link)?

Comment: @ElderGeek is that better ?

Answer (score 1):

Since unity –reset is deprecated and hasn't worked since 12.10,  we have to reset Unity (and Compiz) manually if for some reason we don't want to install `unity-tweak-tool`

First let's make sure we have the tools to do the job.

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

after installation is complete

If you want a listing of your current Compiz settings (before returning them to defaults) you can issue the command `dconf dump /org/compiz/`

we will issue the command

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

To restart unity and apply the changes immediately issue the command

`setsid unity` or reboot.

Sources:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html

https://github.com/phanimahesh/unity-revamp

Comment: @elederGeek. Thank you so much for your answer. But I think there is a deep problem in my system. I see a lot of errors being thrown arounf once I fire the above command. A lot of GLib library and Gtk issues. I think all to do with gstreamer dependencies etc. Even the trash can does not show a file that I put there. It simply deletes it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us which part you did and provide the errors that that command generated. This will certainly help us help you!

Comment: I have edited the question and added the error file also.

Comment: I can duplicate all the warnings and errors that you recieved except for 3 (and my unity resets just fine). I'll look into the 3 I can't reproduce.

Comment: Did the launcher disappear and reappear when you issued the command `setsid unity`?

Comment: Yes it did. Also the command does not exit i.e. it continues to moniter all the applications that are opening. It also make the top menu bar i.e. one where we see battery icon etc disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21455/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-akash-deshpande).

Comment: there seems to be a deep rooted problem. I have asked the following question. Will it be possible for you to check it out ?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/590518/ubuntu-trash-can-does-not-open

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this. And finally found in a blog somewhere that I might need to update Dconf.

So I downloaded the latest version of dconf (dconf-0.22.0) and manually configured and installed it.

This solved the problem. The main reason this was happening is because, it was not able to store the settings anywhere i.e. it was storing the settings in the memory. As result they always got deleted on restart. Hope this helps others.

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved! Could you expand your answer a bit to include the steps you followed so that someone with the same problem could benefit? I thank you and the community thanks you! Ping me when your done and if it's a good answer I'll upvote and boost your rep here!

Comment: @Akash can you share your solution ???

Answer (score 0):

While the OP real issue might differ from mine, the OP title fits well enough and google guided me here while searching for solution.

To rephrase the problem: **all unity settings lost after restart**. Not only sidebar icons, but also desktop wallpaper, custom keyboard shortcuts, etc.

The problem was very simple: a conf file `~/.config/dconf/user` somehow got **owned by root** during system upgrade.

Solution is obvious: change owner back to your user and re-login (no restart needed). To be more clear:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.config/dconf/user
```